# Relationship between C and C++ standard library

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

This question doesn't directly relate to programming or a specific language concept. My question is can we use a reference to the `C` International Standard (for instance `C11`) to provide a *normative* reference to describe any concept from a `C` library in `C++`.

To be more specific, in a header `<climits>` defined in `N3797::18.3.3 [c.limits]` the `C library` header  is described. But the `C` Standard provide more comprehensive information about `<limits.h>`'s content rather than `N3797` working draft.

So everything about the `C library` defined in the `C11` is true for the `C++` implementation defined in `C++11` of `C library` or we can't rely to what the `C` standard provides?

Comment: Related to [Can we apply content not explicitly cited from the normative references to the C++ standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23020323/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour As far as I understood from the asnwer we can use only a referenced part of C standard as normative reference. Right?

Comment: As far as I understand the C++ standard must explicitly refer to a normative reference, we can not refer to part of a normative reference otherwise.

Comment: I moved my above comments into my answer, so we can remove these comments now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the *C standard library* C++ falls back on the C standard and for [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) it falls back on C99 not C11, before C++11 the C standard referenced was C90. This is covered in section `1.2` *Normative references* which says:

> The following referenced documents are indispensable for the
>   application of this document. For dated references, only the edition
>   cited applies. For undated references, the latest edition of the
>   referenced document (including any amendments) applies.

and includes:

> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999, Programming languages — C
> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.1:2001(E), Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 1
> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.2:2004(E), Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 2
> - ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E), Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 3

and also says:

> The library described in Clause 7 of ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and Clause 7 of
>   ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.1:2001 and Clause 7 of ISO/IEC
>   9899:1999/Cor.2:2003 is hereinafter called the C standard library.<sup>1</sup>

The C++ standard uses the term *C standard library* to refer back to C99 and the TCs and will explicitly state when C++ differs from C.

and section `17.2` *The C standard library* says:

> 1. The C++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the
>      C standard library, suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety.
> 2. The descriptions of many library functions rely on the C standard
>      library for the signatures and semantics of those functions. In all
>      such cases, any use of the restrict qualifier shall be omitted.

The *cname* header files which correspond to C Standard Library *name.h* files is covered in `17.6.1.2` *Headers* which says amongst other things:

> Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of
>   each header cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding
>   header name.h, as specified in the C standard library (1.2) or the C
>   Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ standard
>   library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined
>   as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace
>   std. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within
>   the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by
>   explicit using-declarations (7.3.3)

The contents of `climits` as they relate to `limits.h` is covered in section `18.3.3` and says:

> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header .
>   [ Note: The types of the constants defined by macros in  are
>   not required to match the types to which the macros refer.—end note ]

Note, as I mentioned in the comment above, the normative references are not taken as a whole, the C++ standard must make explicit reference to a normative reference for it to apply to the C++ standard. See  [Can we apply content not explicitly cited from the normative references to the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23020323/1708801) for more details.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Particular in the case of `<climits>` header we can rely on what the C Standard says about it, does it?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I think this is what [c.limits]/2 wants to tell us: "The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<limits.h>`" -- as I understand it, "the contents" also covers the specification of the constants etc.