# Parasoft C/C++Test 9.4 , error: invalid type conversion

Tags: c, unit-testing, parasoft

When I used Parasoft c/c++test9.4 with Cygwin gcc11.3 to run unit test, there is such a problem:

```
C++test analysis errors in /example_debug
    1. Test execution: error preparing instrumentation / symbols data for file.
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/mmintrin.h", line 79: error: invalid
          type conversion
    return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si (__i, 0);
           ^

"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/mmintrin.h", line 161: error: 
          invalid type conversion
    return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_packsswb ((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^

"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/mmintrin.h", line 176: error: 
          invalid type conversion
    return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_packssdw ((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^

"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/mmintrin.h", line 191: error: 
          invalid type conversion
    return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_packuswb ((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^

"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/mmintrin.h", line 205: error: 
          invalid type conversion
    return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_punpckhbw ((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^
...
...
...
Compilation terminated.
```

Any hint on this? and how should it be done instead? Thanks in advance

Comment: Pick a language (c or c++). Post corresponding code for one of the errors.  We need to know what __m64 is, and what the functions return.

Comment: @AllanWind Technically 99% of C is also valid C++ as well. Even the C standard library is part of the C++ standard too. Conversely, very little C++ is C-compatible. So if his code is C-compatible there is nothing wrong posting on under a C++ tag from where I stand.

Comment: @MadFred You just made up the  "Technically 99%" didn't you? :-) I just wanted to encourage op to be precise, and tooling may very well be part of the answer.  The standards have diverged, for instance, designated initializes C99 are not supported in C++.  You need to cast void *, say, from malloc in C++ but not in C, etc.

Comment: No, the C++ standard specifically sets the C language as a subset, and that includes the C standard library as well.  https://eel.is/c++draft/library.c

Comment: @MadFred It incorporates the C standard library with some changes as you quote, but does not incorporate the core language and certainly not as a subset. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304506/relationship-between-c-and-c-standard-library and https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.iso for just some differences between C++98 and C89 even before they diverged.

Comment: We are in the border of rhetoric here. So tell me: are Intel Intrinsics written in the C language or the C++ language?

Comment: Apparently the checker software does not recognize `__m64` as a data type. And it is no standard type. How is it defined? And did you tell the checker software about it?

Comment: @MadFred Without having looked into sources, most probably intrinsics are _implemented_ in assembly and compiler-specific language extensions. Their _declaration_ can be written in a way that is conforming to C as well as C++, like many other declarations.

Comment: @MadFred You talked about the standard. I think it is pretty obvious that you can't implement Intel intrinsics in either standard C or standard C++. You need specific compiler-support and probably a lot of assembly. But a compiler supporting them will also support enough language extensions that it will be possible to offer the intended intrinsics interface for C and C++ user code.

Comment: @MadFred Noone is denying that the subset of C which is also valid C++ is large. 99% seems to overstate it though. Most C code with a dynamic allocation will for example fail as C++ if not intentionally written for both because of the missing explicit cast of the return value of `malloc`. Functions using `restrict` will also fail. Narrowing initialization with braces fails in C++ but not C. Then there are VLA and similar C-only constructs. And also there are e.g. type-punning and object lifetime rules which are much stricter in C++ (although compilers are typically relaxed on that).

Comment: @thebusybee intel intrinsics are not compiler builtins or compiler extensions.

Comment: @user17732522 You don't need any compiler support other than standar C/C++ to implement intel intrinsics. Can you give me an example of such?

Comment: @MadFred You can prove your claim with some references, don't you?

Comment: The intel intrinsics are C/C++ headers that may call gcc/clang builtins, you can see that eg in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include/emmintrin.h`.   Those headers are completely valid C or C++ code.  Eg EVE is a project that makes heavy use of intrinsices in C++20 https://github.com/jfalcou/eve

Comment: @MadFred That file is full of `__attribute__`, `__extension__` and other compiler extensions. None of these are valid C or C++ by the standard, their use makes the program have undefined behavior implying that the standards impose no requirements on how compilers will deal with such a program. These are all compiler extensions to the standard language, which is the point.

Comment: @user17732522 I did not know that StackOverflow's "c++" tag excluded any questions that touched on compiler extensions. Is that a fact or just your opinion?

Comment: @MadFred I did not claim that as either fact or opinion. I am arguing about only your comments "_No, the C++ standard specifically sets the C language as a subset,_" and "_Technically [!] 99% of C is also valid C++ as well._". It is completely fine to ask about non-standard C++ features as long as the compiler(s) which the question is about are mentioned. This question does for example nothing wrong in that regard. Unfortunately it is about a proprietary tool, so that the set of users that can reproduce the problem is going to be limited. It lacks a [mre] as well, making it even harder.

Comment: Perhaps, it is prudent to factor into our consideration that `GCC version 11` is not within the supported compiler version in your specific installation of this tool. What do you think?